# Custom NSArray Class definition

Tags: objective-c, macos, inheritance, foreach

I try to write my own class in objective-c. I declared a class variable `NSArray *_people` in it. I set all setters and getters and everything works fine for me but.. A silly easy question. When I want to query my array with a 'for' loop It must go like this:

```
for (NSString *s in [myClass people])
```

How do I achieve the same behavior as with a usual `NSArray` class instance like this?:

```
for (NSString *s in people)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep people array property private, then you should implement `NSFastEnumeration` protocol in your new class. Custom implementation is quite dificult (buffering, change mutation flag, pointers and size), but your case it is pretty simple.

In your `.m` file  you should implement:

```
- (NSUInteger)countByEnumeratingWithState:(NSFastEnumerationState *)state objects:(id __unsafe_unretained [])buffer count:(NSUInteger)len {
    return [self.people countByEnumeratingWithState:state objects:buffer count:len];
}
```

And in your header file:

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject<NSFastEnumeration>
```

Answer (score 0):

***MyClass.h***

```
@interface MyClass
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *people;
@end
```

Now, you can access the array like...

```
for(NSString *s in [myclass people])
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I must do now. Yet I need the other way. Just to say "for (NSString *s in myClass)"